# Why won't XBMC play my DVDs?

Tags: dvd, xbmc

I installed XBMC using the Ubuntu Software Centre along with some codec packs on a fresh install of 12.04 today. I tested it with all kinds of media and everything ran great except for DVDs. Ubuntu and XBMC acknowledge there is a disc in the drive, but when I prompt XBMC to play it, it loads for a second and then stops.

Any ideas about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Could you please add some more information to your question? E.g.: Do DVDs play in any other video players (e.g. Totem, VLC)?

Comment: Installing Libdvdcss fixed the problem. Thank you so much and sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

could be a problem of codec? 
install  [ubuntu-restricted-extras [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras) 
if you are on Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04
and retry ...

Else if you are on Ubuntu 13.04, **ubuntu-restricted-extras** does not seem available yet

Comment: That was part of the codecs I installed.

Comment: @Scoria Then I suggest you to specify that by editing your question, and to kill the idea that it could be a problem of codec, perhaps add example of applications that you tested successfully to read your DVD (like VLC). Also add your Ubuntu version. Hope that people with more knowlege than me could help you ...